# Intermittent issue - duplicate emails being sent

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

I have some code to send emails in my APP_CODE directory:

Dim message As Mail.MailMessage = New Mail.MailMessage(strFrom, strSendTo)

```
    Dim SMTP_Client As Mail.SmtpClient = New Mail.SmtpClient("mymailserver.mycompany.com")

    'Send email
    Try
        message.Priority = Mail.MailPriority.Normal
        message.IsBodyHtml = True
        message.Subject = strSubject
        message.Body = strBody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "THIS IS AN AUTOMATED MESSAGE. DO NOT REPLY."
        SMTP_Client.Send(message)
```

The problem is some users will **intermittently** receive duplicate emails. It doesn't appear to be a code issue.  When I step through the code, I can see the calls to send the email only fire once. I thought maybe the code was being called in Page_Load, but stepping through the code shows Page_Load firing before my button click event.

I'm wondering if this couldn't be a problem on our SMTP relay; if it is, does anyone know things I should tell my server admin to monitor?

**EDIT**

There's some code that checks the values of two form fields before sending the email. The second field is updated during page load, and I can see that if the values are the same no email is triggered. When I make a change, the email gets sent, but I always get one and only one.

Comment: Are you sure users are not double-clicking the button? There are still plenty of folks that do that....

Comment: Hi E.J. - positive that's not happening. I've clicked the button twice myself and it sends one email to me on my dev site. That was the first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, your first step should be isolating the problem to either the code or the exchange server. You can do this by adding some logging to your code.

Each time an email is sent out by code, log this event along with all the pertinent information (ie: date sent, email addresses, process that sent email, etc).

Now when you receive a duplicate email, you can check your logs to see if the code sent out the email multiple times or not.

Isolating this one fact before you start delving deeper into the problem is sure to save you some time finding the problem.

Comment: It turned out to be the old Exchange server. The server is known to intermittently send multiple copies of emails (duplicates, sometimes even triplicates). Updating it to our new hardware will probably fix the problem.